# How to add Query String Auth on all files in Django with Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

I am using Django with Amazon s3 with Libraries(django-storages boto3)

To be specific the base.css is being served and fonts.css is not being served(Err 403).
This is happening in Django Admin Console.
I have confirmed that the fonts.css is in the bucket

The problem being these files don't have query string auth

```
# This is working
GET https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/base.css?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AFD34GE4VTLUKQOTHAW7%2F20210726%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210726T193438Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=815bd068805f60f90c6acf27b24028424e85afbf7ba2939b51471cab2ba8e8b9

# This isn't working
GET https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/fonts.css
```

Almost all static files are being served

- The fonts.css is not in the HTML page source and maybe is being called from a JS code that is not appending the Query String Auth
- Also when I shift from S3 to django default storage, it works perfectly fine.